# Windows 10 unable to connect to Internet through proxy

Tags: networking, google-chrome, proxy, windows-update, windows-10-preview

I am on Windows 10 Insider Build **10162**. I use a **proxy** to connect to internet. Internet works fine on both Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome. But when I try to ping **Google.com** from cmd, it says **"Request timed out"**.
I have tried to set proxy using:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy <proxy address>:<port>
```

It shows that the proxy was set properly, but ping still does not work so does Windows Update. Is this a bug in Windows or possible problem with my system?

Comment: What host are you tring to `ping`?. Not all hosts respond to `ping` requests. Did you try a well know host like `ping www.google.com`?

Comment: Yes , I tried to ping `www.google.com`

Comment: What does `tracert www.google.com` show?

Comment: [Tracert](http://pastebin.com/asfpZrvZ). It is working perfectly fine in Chrome & IE

Comment: Looks like your router / proxy is blocking ping / tracert. Who controls the proxy? Your ISP? What kind of internet connection do you have?

Comment: My university controls the proxy. I am using ethernet connection

Comment: Then you need to speak to your university IT department. Presumably they have disabled ping for a good reason.